# how to use chef-solo to install a particular version of nginx

Tags: nginx, apt-get, chef-solo

I have the following and it doesn't work:

```
package 'nginx' do
  action :install 
  version "1.1.19" 
end
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using recipe `nginx::source`. Here is example configuration of role, but you can use it anywhere you want.

```
{
  "name": "production",
  "chef_type": "role",
  "json_class": "Chef::Role",
  "description": "The base role for systems that serve HTTP traffic",
  "override_attributes": {
    "nginx": {
      "version": "1.7.3",
      "default_site_enabled": true,
      "source": {
        "modules": ["nginx::http_gzip_static_module"],
        "version": "1.7.3"
      }
    }
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[nginx::source]",
    "recipe[my_app]"
  ]
}
```